# getRangeAt(0) bug in MS Edge, workaround?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where users can highlight text in a PDF file, and then use getSelection(), getRangeAt(), and getClientRects() to save the boundaries of the highlight for future reference.  The problem I'm running into is Microsoft Edge appears to have a bug when executing getRangeAt(0) if the selection crosses elements with position:absolute.  See below fiddle and view console in both Edge (broken) and Chrome/Firefox (working as expected).  After running in Edge, remove the position:absolute style and run again, Edge now correctly returns the expected rects.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lbgce2km/2/

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  let sel = window.getSelection();
  let range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  let rects = range.getClientRects();
  
  //check console for result.
  console.log('Rects:  ', rects);
});
```

```css
div {
  position:absolute
}
```

```html
    <div style='margin-top: 10px'>Microsoft Edge is the default web browser on Windows 10, Windows 10 Mobile, and Xbox One consoles, replacing Internet Explorer 11 and Internet Explorer Mobile. engine</div>
    <div style='margin-top: 75px' >
    Microsoft initially announced that Edge would support the legacy Trident (MSHTML) layout engine for backwards compatibility, but later said that, due to "strong feedback", Edge would use a new engine, while Internet Explorer would continue to provide the legacy
    </div>
    <div style='margin-top: 175px'>
      The browser includes an integrated Adobe Flash Player (with an internal whitelist allowing Flash applets on Facebook websites to load automatically, bypassing all other security controls requiring user activation)[15] and a PDF reader. It also supports asm.js.
    </div>
```

I've tried working around problem by creating an additional range, setting the position equal to that of the selected range, then extracting the contents of the selected range and insert that inside of a span into the additional range, then returning the rects of the span but it's of course out of place.

```js
const sel = window.getSelection();
const range = sel.getRangeAt(0)

let addRange = document.createRange();
addRange.setStart(sel.anchorNode, sel.anchorOffset);
addRange.setEnd(sel.focusNode, sel.focusOffset);
let span = document.createElement("span");
let con = range.extractContents();
span.appendChild(con);
addRange.insertNode(span);
```

Anyone have any suggestions on a possible workaround?